# Help me derive this basic trigonometry identity

Tags: trigonometry

$$-\sin^2(x)+1 = \cos^2(x)$$
I saw this identity and I want to know how you derive it.

Comment: Draw the unit circle on the coordinate plane.  Draw a right triangle whose base is on the x-axis and whose segment begins at (0,0) and at (a,0). The other leg goes from (a,0) to (a,b).  The hypotenuse is formed from (0,0) to (a,b). Find cosine and sine of the angle formed between the hypotenuse and base. Also use pythagorean theorem to find a relationship between the sides of the right triangle.

Comment: Oops and (a,b) is a point on the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

By Pythagoras theorem,

> $a^2+b^2=c^2$
>
> $(\frac{a}{c})^2+(\frac{b}{c})^2=1$
>
> $\cos^2x +  \sin^2x=1$

or

$$1-\sin^2x=\cos^2x$$

Answer (score 1):

This is called the trigonometric Pythagoras. I give you two ways to obtain the identity.

**Method 1:** We use the Euler-identity $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \varphi} = \cos(\varphi) + \mathrm{i} \sin (\varphi)$ for every $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$. With this we have

$$1 = \mathrm{e}^0 = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\varphi - \mathrm{i}\varphi} = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\varphi}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\varphi} = \big(\cos(\varphi) + \mathrm{i} \sin(\varphi)\big)\big(\cos(-\varphi) + \mathrm{i} \sin(-\varphi)\big) = \cos^2(\varphi) + \sin^2(\varphi)$$

since $\cos(-\varphi) = \cos(\varphi)$ and $\sin(-\varphi) = - \sin(\varphi)$.

**Method 2:** Define the real - valued function $f(x) := \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is differentiable with derivative

$$f'(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x) \equiv 0,$$

hence $f$ must be constant: $f \equiv c$ with an unknown $c \in \mathbb{R}$. For knowing the value of a constant function everywhere, it clearly suffices to know the value at one point. Since $f(0) = \cos^2(0) + \sin^2(0) = 1$, it follows $f \equiv 1$. We obtain

$$1 = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x). $$

Comment: I saw you on papa flammy youtube video :o

Comment: @003264_ Yes, he is a friend of mine. We studied math together.

Answer (score 0):

We wish to prove that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$. Consider a right-angled triangle with one of the angles as $x$. Now $sin^2(x) = \frac{o^2}{h^2}, cos^2(x) = \frac{a^2}{h^2}$ where $o, a, h$ are the opposite side, adjacent side, and the hypothenuse. But $o^2 + a^2 = h^2$ by Pythagoras's theorem, so $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = \frac{o^2+a^2}{h^2} = 1$.

Comment: "hypotenuse", not "hypothenuse".